# Finding replaceable push pull transformer with similar specifications

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-engineering

I am a student and is making power project using Push-Pull transformer. I used the Reference design: [TI Designs: TIDA-01352](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-01352). I stuck to find 2 replaceable Push-Pull transformers as in suggesting transformers(750340744 & 750343547 of Wurth Electronik).

These are two datasheets of the transformer I want to replace.

750343547: https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/750343547.pdf

750340744: https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/750340744.pdf

I tried to find on Mouser, Digikey, etc. Could you suggest me to find there transformers with above similar specifications?

P/S: I sent to Wruk Electronik to ask, but they want more information about name project, company name, my job, the price I want, etc. It made me confused. That is reseason why I want to replace them with similar specifications

Comment: those two sheets describe radically different parts. what parameters are important?

Comment: The turn ratio is the importance.

Answer (score 0):

On digikey you'll find that sort of thing under "pulse transformers",
on element14 under "coupled inductors"
on mouser under "coupled inductors" again.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I found 2 types. But I still wonder about the Turns ratio of the push-pull transformer.

Answer (score 0):

For the current transformer(750340744), I found a replaceable one: [53100C](https://www.murata-ps.com/pub/data/magnetics/kmp_5300c.pdf) with turn ratio: 1:100; primary current rating 10A.

For the push-pull transformer(750340744), I found a replaceable one: [PH9385.015NL](https://kr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/336/P766-1144949.pdf). But I still wonder about turns ratio. The datasheet said that: Turns Ratio
(1:4):(8:5) = 1:5. In my design, pin 2 ties to pin 3 and pin 7 ties to pin 6. And I want Turns Ratio (1-2):(8-7) = 1:5 ; (1-2):(6-5)=1:5; (1-2):(3-4) = 1:1. So, whether this transformer is what I need?

[image]